# ngFor to display object data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to display *all* the .name and .info elements for `actor` and `character` objects shown below, using *ngFor.
[image: object]

I create the object here in my **resultpage.component**:

```
this.actorInfo = [{actor: res.actorInfo, character: this.characters}];
```

and here is my html for running through the elements in **resultpage.html**:

```
<div class="castMembers">
  <div class="member" *ngFor="let item of actorInfo">
    <span class="character">{{item.name}}</span>
    <span class="actor">{{item.info}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code does not output any errors, but it  also does not output any information. I believe this is due to the first element on the object being *0:*. But trying `*ngFor="let item[0] of actorInfo"` causes major problems in Angular.

How can I display *all* the `name` and `info` items in my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have two nested ngFor,

```
<div class="castMembers">
  <div class="member" *ngFor="let item of actorInfo">
    <div class="member" *ngFor="let actor of item.actorInfo ">
    <span class="character">{{actor.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="member" *ngFor="let character of item.character">
    <span class="actor">{{character.info}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this:

```
<div class="castMembers">
<div class="member" *ngFor="let item of actorInfo">
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block">
            <span class="character" *ngFor="let actor of item?.actor">
                {{actor.name}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; display: inline-block">
            <span class="actor" *ngFor="let character of item?.character">
                {{character.info}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ketan is there something different logic than @Sajeetharan answers

Comment: is just display  character info beside actor name. so it look like table list

Comment: But the question is not tag for css or styles the user just want solution for displaying the data using for loop

Comment: it will display as you wanted